# Any better way to check string for valid IPv4 and IPv6?

Tags: python, ipv6, ipv4

I have the following task:

Identify if the string has a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address using just the default modules. I've found an interesting method using socket module here it is:

```
import socket

ip = '10.1.0.10'
try:
    # test for IPv4
    socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET, ip)
except socket.error:
    try:
        # test for IPv6 
        socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, ip)
    except socket.error:
        print(ip, " is not valid")
```

It seems ugly to have a try under a try in such case, is there a better way?
Is there a different module that could accomplish the same in a better way considering the fact that I have to check about 100 IP's.

Comment: It's not bad, though.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple regex (http://www.regextester.com/22) suffice?

Comment: With valid: do you mean that there exists a node with the ip address, or that you can set up a node with that address. After all only a subset of the allowed ip addresses is allocated.

Comment: If it is valid, do you need to tell if it's V4 or V6? if not, it will suffice to have both `socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET, ip)` and `socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, ip)` under the same `try-except` clause. If either one fails it will get caught.

Comment: I'm checking if what's in "ip" variable contains a valid IPv6 or IPv4, it doesn't matter if it's in use or not.

I can't put them under the same try-except as if one of the dose not fail it should be accepted as a valid IP but with your suggestion if ip contains ipv4 the it will still fail

Answer (score 7):

You can use the ipaddress module. Documentation can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html

Sample code:

```
>>> ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.0.1')
IPv4Address('192.168.0.1')
>>> ipaddress.ip_address('2001:db8::')
IPv6Address('2001:db8::')
>>> ipaddress.ip_address('323.4.7.8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ipaddress.py", line 54, in ip_address
    address)
ValueError: '323.4.7.8' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address
>>> ipaddress.ip_address('ffff::4543:1f1f::134')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ipaddress.py", line 54, in ip_address
    address)
ValueError: 'ffff::4543:1f1f::134' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address
```

Comment: Not in Python 2.x I guess?

Comment: It has actually been backported to 2.6

Comment: that would be nice except is not part of the default modules. I have to use python2

Comment: @KacperReutt I don't find a link to standard 2.x module? Even if so, including a test case would be helpful.

Comment: there's also a IPy module but again, not available by default

Comment: @SantoshKumar - you're right - it's not a default module in 2.7. It exists in my 2.7 and since I incorrectly assumed it's a standard as in 3.